# javascript to add class to body based on url

Tags: javascript

I have two domains and both have the same web page. Same HTML CSS and content.
foo.com and bar.com

Both websites reside in the same hosting and return the same files. This way I don't have to duplicate the changes in both domains. I just edit one file and both domains are updated.

Now I want to change some colors on foo.com and hide some elements on bar.com but still don't want to duplicate the website.

I want a JavaScript code snippet that can detect the current URL of the page and add class to the body. It would be nice if there is something that can detect only domain.

Comment: Try with `window.location.host` to get `host` or `window.location.href` to get full url.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```js
if(window.location.href == 'https://stacksnippets.net/js'){
  $("#demo").addClass('demoClass');
}
```

```css
.demoClass{
color: green;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo">Color changed as per url change</p>
```

Comment: You should use `window.location.host` or you need to use find url from `href`, Because it may possible of someone append `querystring` then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) in javascript. Add some custom logic aswell.

```js
// Get the current browser url.
const url = window.location.href;
console.log(url);
// Selecting the body tag
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
// Adding a custom check to check whether the url contains our domain.
if (url.indexOf('stacksnippets') > -1) {
    body.className += ' class-one';
} else {
    body.className += ' class-two';
}
```

```css
.class-one {
    color: blue;
}

.class-two {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>JavaScript</h2>

  <h3>The window.location object</h3>
</body>
```

Comment: You defined body as const, and later you are assigning value to it!! is it supported??

Comment: @Omar Yes it is. You are not reassigning the const object. Just updating the properties of that object.

Comment: @Omar, Yes with `const` you can change `property` or invoke `function` of `object` but you can not reassign value like later you will not be able to write `body = 10`.

Comment: You should use `body.className = body.className + ' ' + 'class-one';` otherwise if `body` already has class it will remove existing one and add new one.

Comment: @Karan that could be better i think. Added that.

Answer (score 1):

put below in `script` at the end of body:

You can use jquery as well. In short use documet/winod load event to put your host based logic.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var isFoo = window.location.href.indexOf('foo.com') > -1;
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var class = isFoo ? 'foo-class' : 'bar-class';
  body.className = body.className + ' '+ class;
  
})
```

Comment: You need to add space (`' '`) before here `body.className + ' ' + class;` otherwise if `body` has class `abc` then it will become `abcfoo-class`. But expected value is `abc foo-class`.